# Dopesheet summary not showing

Tags: animation, dopesheet

Even though I have an armature with two actions and many keyframes assigned to it, my dopesheet summary is not showing. The button at the bottom of the dopesheet window should toggle the summary but it doesn't. I've also checked the NLA editor and have switch between the different views in Dopesheet window(Action editor and normal dopesheet view). Still empty.

[image: As you can see the Summary is tuned on but it's still empty]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your dope sheet window scrolled down too far.  Press <kbd>Home</kbd> button to refresh the view